# No entry in db throw error in form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have the following code in the controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('email', 'email', array(
                    'constraints' => array(new MaxLength(array('limit' => 255, 'message' => 'email.maxlength'))),
                    'required' => true,
                    'attr' => array('oninvalid' => "setCustomValidity('" . $this->get('translator')->trans('email.oninvalid', array(), 'validators') . "')",
                        'placeholder' => $this->get('translator')->trans('email.placeholder', array(), 'validators'),)
                ))
                ->getForm();
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        $formData = $form->getData();

        if ($form->isValid()) {
        $formData->getEmail();
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $rep = $em->getRepository('FrontendAccountBundle:User');
                $q = $rep->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->join('u.state', 's')
                        ->where('u.email = :email')
                        ->andWhere('s.id = :sid')
                        ->setParameters(array('email' => $email))
                        ->getQuery();

                try {
                    $user = $q->getSingleResult();
                } catch (\Doctrine\Orm\NoResultException $e) {
                    //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('frontend_account_unknown_email'));
                }
} 
return $this->render('FrontendAccountBundle::send_new_activation_link.html.php', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
```

Is there a way to throw an error in the form that the email address is unknown in the db, instead of creating a new action?

Or did I miss something in the docs?

Comment: I don't understand. where do you create a new action?

Comment: Actually I was redirecting in the catch part to another action. But I want to stay in the same action and just throwing an error that the email address is not in the db. Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ***throw an error*** so either don't catch it in the first place, or catch all the exceptions and re-throw only the one you want.

If you want to add an error to the form, you can create a [FormError](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormError.php) and simply add it to the form:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;

...

catch (\Doctrine\Orm\NoResultException $e) {
    $form->addError(new FormError('the e-mail was not found'));
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I make it visible in the template-form? I updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants to see the complete code.

```
$form->addError(new FormError('the e-mail was not found'));

$templating = $this->container->get('templating');

$response = new Response($templating->render('FrontendAccountBundle::send_new_activation_link.html.php', array(
                         'form' => $form->createView()
                         )));
$response->send();
```